# When there are X New Questions, the views don't update untill you refresh the page

Tags: feature-request, live-refresh

First, you see the banner:

[image]

Then you click it and the 5 new questions appear:

[image]

But all of them have 0 votes, 0 answers and 1 view. You have to refresh to see the real numbers:

[image]

Comment: I think this should be a feature request - this isn't *supposed* to happen AFAIK, because if you look at the data the WebSockets return - it **only gives new question info *when it arrives*...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I've tagged it with both, as I'm not sure. I seem to remember it maybe used to...?

Comment: maybe... but I'm 99% sure it hasn't...! Let's wait for someone else to confirm! :)

Comment: Yeh I really can't remember. Either way, it kinda defeats the point of the button - you may as well refresh the page!

Comment: I just looked at the WebSocket's data: the data returned says '1 view' '0 answers' and '0 votes', so *if it did happen*, there was another process that updated the numbers

Comment: +1 I have noticed this and thought of asking but was not sure of "blame cache" thing

Comment: @HackerKarma it's one of the things I've been meaning to post just haven't got around to it untill now :)

Comment: @Tim  ᔕᖺᘎᕊ has raised an interesting point here "data the WebSockets return..." Let's wait n see for a official response.